# Calculate how wide text is?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's a screenshot of what I'm dealing with:

[image: Problem]

As you can see, the spacing between all of the words (tutorials, blog, news, contact) isn't the same.  I have the divs set an equal distance apart and the text-align equal to center.  So, I'm guessing the reason for this problem is that the length of each word isn't the same.

So, any idea on how I could calculate how wide each word is and space them accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8x7b/1/

Basically set a fixed margin-right between your div's and you should be set :)

Comment: I just tried that.  It put all of my divs on top of each other.

Comment: Nvm, had to remove absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2):

What about simply aligning items on the right and applying a right margin (or padding) to them?

```
  item 1|   item 2|   item 3|   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm inclined to agree with Andreas answer as its more than likely your margins on your div elements.

If you created a jsfiddle to provide us your source code, you'd increase your ability to get a precise answer to your specific question.

there are several resources you can use as well including jsfiddle.net as mentioned above, to test just your HTML and CSS.

I understand that there are many ways to approach the same result but I'm curious as to why you're using separate div elements for each link. This increases the weight of your page, making it extremely div heavy and reduces meaning in your code.

I would suggest something like this in the future: link to tinkerbin.com no longer valid.